# I have common Child entity for different parent entities how to handle this in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have Parent1, Parent2... like up to 4 parents and one Child entity that has a relationship.
And i am maintaining parenttype and parentid to have the relationship

```
Parent1
id Name
1  Parent1-1 

Parent2
id name
1  Parent2-1

Child
id name.     parenttype parentid
1  Child1    Parent1  1 
1  Child2    Parent2  1 


@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT1")
public class Parent1 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PARENT1_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class,   cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT1_ID")
    private List<Child> chidList = new ArrayList<>();

    .........
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT2")
public class Parent2 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PARENT2_ID", unique = true, nullable = false
    private String id;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class,   cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT2_ID")
    private List<Child> chidList = new ArrayList<>();
    .........
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected String id;

    @Column(name = "PARENT_TYPE" )
    private String parentType;

    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private String parentId;
    .........
}
```

While persisting i am getting contraint violation exception, but if have only one parent its working.
How to achieve this

Comment: How are you persisting? Show us the code. What is the stack trace that you get? Which SQL queries are executed?

Comment: I am using spring-boot and am using Parent1Repo.saveall, So I was more interested in what to do to persist this to achieve this

Comment: I have added all the data and trying to saveAll, Could you help me with this

Comment: Add the information I asked for and then I can help